# ALERT! /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root does not exist. Dropping to a shell!

Tags: boot, 19.04, lvm

As of last night my Ubuntu 19.04 laptop won’t boot into its latest kernel. In the hours beforehand I had completed an apt-get upgrade and autoremove. The system continued along perfectly fine. After a reboot however, I reach an (intramfs) shell prompt.

Typing exit at this prompt I am then given the alert message:

ALERT! /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root does not exist. Dropping to a shell!

I have discovered that I can successfully boot into an older kernel through the grub menu.

Latest installed kernel: 5.0.0-25-generic (not working

Backup kernel: 5.0.0-21-generic (working)

My system runs an LVM partitioned drive.

I found an old thread with the same symptoms that advised running ls /dev/mapper at the intramfs shell. All that returns is /dev/mapper/control

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also, if there’s more info required please just let me know.

TIA

Comment: Have you tried logging into the old kernel and doing a `sudo update-grub`?  It sounds like an update didn't complete properly, so your initramfs is missing the libraries to load LVM.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @tudor, unfortunately it made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo update-initramfs -u -k 5.0.0-25-generic
```

This updates the initrid from not running kernel.

If it is not working show

```
sudo update-initramfs -uv -k 5.0.0-25-generic
```

Verbose (-v) can show us some hint what is going wrong.