# ALERT! /dev/mmcblk1p1 does not exist. Dropping to a shell!

Tags: boot, 20.04, bootloader, arm

can someone please shed some light on the situation. I have SoM FETA40i-C/ SBC OKA40i-C installed on a custom board. During boot process OS won't boot randomly into an interactive shell, it stucks with the message "**ALERT! /dev/mmcblk1p1 does not exist. Dropping to a shell!**". After hard reboot, it will boot into os or maybe not, but in most cases (98%) it will boot into Ubuntu.
I've attached logs with a success boot and a unsuccessfull boot.
I've read that increasing a rootdelay may help, so I've added rootdelay=180 to the  /boot/boot.scr, but the module stopped to boot at all.
Also, from [this poste](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1166074/alert-dev-mapper-ubuntu-vg-root-does-not-exist-dropping-to-a-shell) next command also made a brick from my module - it won't boot at all after that:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u -k 5.0.0-25-generic
```

I gave Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS.

I've attached /etc/fstab, /boot/boot.scr also to this [google drive folder](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1r2nXN6ppJcHAKQ6VW3QVuik46g9rwaBA?usp=sharing)
Also, here are some quotes from those files:

- /etc/fstab

  `UUID=5620ac6e-d96b-409e-8d4e-f650b62e2116 / ext4 defaults,noatime,commit=600,errors=remount-ro 0 1 tmpfs /tmp tmpfs defaults,nosuid 0 0`
- /proc/cmdline

`root=/dev/mmcblk1p1 rootwait rootfstype=ext4 earlycon console=ttyS0,115200 hdmi.audio=EDID:0 disp.screen0_output_mode=1920x1080p60 consoleblank=0 loglevel=7 ubootpart= ubootsource=mmc usb-storage.quirks=0x2537:0x1066:u,0x2537:0x1068:u fsck=force fsck.repair=yes  sunxi_ve_mem_reserve=0 sunxi_g2d_mem_reserve=0 sunxi_fb_mem_reserve=16 cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1`

- unsuccessfull boot log

> 2022-09-02 20:21:42,730 INFO info(35) Begin: Waiting for root file
> system ... 2022-09-02 20:21:43,763 INFO info(35) Begin: Running
> /scripts/local-block ... done.
>
> done.
>
> Gave up waiting for root file system device.  Common problems:
>
> - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
>
>   - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
> - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
>
> ALERT!  /dev/mmcblk1p1 does not exist.  Dropping to a shell!